# Moving files on a Mac Pro

Tags: macos

I am new to Mac and need to replace some files that are drilled down deep in sub folders. Is there any easy way to copy and paste them without using the command prompt

Comment: should this be on super user?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what files you need to replace? and with what?

Answer (score 0):

You can open multiple Finder windows with ⌘-n (hold command and press n) and then simply drag and drop the files from one folder to another.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can also simply use `⌘-C` and `⌘-V` to copy and paste files, just like you copy and paste text. Select the file you want to copy and press ⌘-c. Navigate to the folder you want to copy it to and press ⌘-v.

You will be prompted to replace if there are preexisting files with the same file name.